What polyfill exists for CSS :has() support in older browsers?
I used a lot of :has() selectors in my CSS(styled-components) code, just to find out that we need to support older browsers for now. Since I can't achieve same results using CSS only, I would like to find a polyfill that would support older versions of browsers, approx 5 years back. I found this one, but it turned out not suitable because of it's limitations. Are there any polyfills that will be supporting full functionality of :has() and work with styled-components?
